# API call with NgRx?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm supposed to generate an API call from a random API site with NgRx, the browser should be showing an input, in which as I write something it should pop up a word or multiple words from the API according to the letters I've written.

I have just started experimenting with NgRx and whilst I'm starting to understand the general flow, I'm having a hard time building up a working code for this task.
Can you please help me?

Inside the app folder of ngrx I have created a "call" folder which contains **call.actions.ts**, **call.reducer.ts**, **call.selector.ts**, **call.state.ts**

Here's what I've written so far:

src/app/call/call.state.ts

```
export interface ICall {
  readonly query: string;
}
```

src/app/call/call.actions.ts

```
import { createAction, props } from '@ngrx/store';
import { ICall } from './call.state';

export const searchQueryChanged = createAction(
  '[Wherever] Search query changed',
  props<{ query: string }>()
);
```

src/app/call/call.reducer.ts

```
import { createReducer, on, Action } from '@ngrx/store';

import { ICall } from './call.state';
import { searchQueryChanged } from './call.actions';

export const initialState: ICall = {
  query: '',
};

createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(searchQueryChanged, (state, { query }) => ({
    ...state,
    query,
  }))
);
```

src/app/app.component.html

```
<input
  [value]="query$ | async"
  (input)="queryTextChanged($event.target.value)"
/>
```

src/app/app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { searchQueryChanged } from './call/call.actions';
import { getQuery } from './call/call.selectors';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'ngrx-ex-api';
}
class SearchThingComponent {
  
  readonly query$ = this.store.select(getQuery);
  
  queryTextChanged(query: string) {
    this.store.dispatch(searchQueryChanged({ query });
  }
}
class SearchThingComponent {
  suggestions$ = this.query$.pipe(
    switchMap(query => doTheThing)
  );
  query$: any;
}
```

src/app/call.selectors.ts

```
import { createSelector, createFeatureSelector } from '@ngrx/store';
import { ICall } from './call.state';

export const whateverFeatureSelector = createFeatureSelector<ICall>('call');
export const getQuery = createSelector(
  whateverFeatureSelector,
  (state) => state.query
);
```

Currently both **app.component.html** and **app.component.ts** present errors which I don't really know how to solve.
If you have in mind another way to address the problem please tell me, thank you.

Comment: Why do you have two class SearchThingComponent classes

Comment: In NgRx you usually do API calls inside effects (createEffect). The effect listens to an action - performs the API call - and responds with a new action (a success version of your triggering action).

Comment: Can you also share the errors you get?